# Git ignore SSH key and prompt for credential

Tags: git, github, ssh

I would like to push code to a Github repository from a location that has been configured with a read-only deploy key.

Currently, a `git push` results in:

> ERROR: The key you are authenticating with has been marked as read only.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Is there a way to trigger a one-time exception that prompts me to enter my credentials instead?

Comment: Have you tried `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /path/to/read-write-key" git push`?

Comment: I'd like to use the actual username/password prompt instead of a read-write key, if possible.

Comment: If you want to use a username/password, you want https URL for your remote URL, not ssh. ssh on github is all key-based.

Comment: Got it. Followed [this](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) in case anyone else comes by this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to change the URL of your existing remote, then you can add a new one:

```
git remote add https https://github.com/username/repo.git
git push https
```

Then you don't have to change back and forth.